# SQL Query to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate actually. Having problems to create criteria object of the sql query below. Would you please lead me ?

```
SELECT P1.*,O1.PROJECT_OID FROM POINTALL P1
LEFT JOIN
OPERATION_PLAN O1
ON P1.OID = O1.GEOVISION_POINT_OID;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your **POINTALL** and **OPERATION_PLAN** table are mapped than only criteria will work otherwise use HQL or SQL.

This is what you need to create

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(POINTALL.class,"P1");

ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList(); 
projections.add(Projections.property("P1.something"),"aliasName");
projections.add(Projections.property("P1.something"),"aliasName");
..
projections.add(Projections.property("O1.PROJECT_OID"),"PROJECT_OID");

criteria.createAlias("P1.OPERATION_PLAN","O1", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);

criteria.setProjection(projections);
```

Comment: then i get the following exception : org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: OPERATION_PLAN of: com.blabla.PointAll

Comment: Get the exact name which have you specified in PointAll bean for `OPERATION_PLAN`

Comment: pointAll is a view and operationPlan is a table. the only relation between them is pointOid. so no any relation with operationPlan in pointAll.

Comment: Than you can not use criteria api, try native sql or hql

Answer (score 0):

You need not create criteria. You can execute native SQL queries or even write the same query in HQL which is very similar to SQL.

Comment: I am aware of HQL but i will need to add restrictions dynamically. that is my problem

Comment: If the two entities are related (or mapped), then you can do it via criteria else HQL is the way.